# Android QR Code Scanning in Smartface 4.5 giving exception

Tags: smartface.io

I have developed an application in Smartface 4.4 which has a QR Code Reader in which the QR code are not auto-focusing. So i went to smartface 4.5.0 and tried with the sample code on the website https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/codereader/

but got the exception 
**Can't find Variable SMFImageCode** .

Then I tried he Code-reader object and debugged it and I got the following exception.

[image]

Please help to get this solved anyone.